# Worklight 6.1 hybrid app return param from native to hybrid

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using IBM worklight 6.1 to build an hybrid app.
There's any api like following scenario; 
- a certain function that need to run on native code and send the result to JavaScript code.

in Worklight 6.2, we can use "`WL.getInstance().sendActionToJS("param", data);`" at .java file and `WL.App.addActionReceiver("param", actionReceiver);` at .js file.

Can anyone advise me for workaround at Worklight 6.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Cordova plug-in that will "bridge" between the JS layer and the native layer. [See these tutorials for Worklight 6.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html), and in particular the "[Android - Adding native functionality to hybrid application with Apache Cordova plugin](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_05_Android_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf)" tutorial and its accompanying [sample application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/AndroidApacheCordovaPluginProject.zip).

The sample application sends data from the JS layer to the native layer, combines data from both and returns it to JS layer, so in your case you could just return data...

You can also see it better illustrated in the following for v7.1. You cannot use the sample app in 6.1 (as it is meant for 7.1), but the JavaScript is the same: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

The steps would be:

1. Execute a Cordova plug-in: `cordova.exec(pluginSuccess, pluginFailure, "mypluginname", "myNativeClass name", []);`
2. Have the class process what is needed
3. Return data to pluginSuccess as described in the tutorial code

Comment: Thanks. I follow the example and I get the data return from native function.